# PostgreSQL: Column Reference in Foreign Key Constraint Does Not Exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-9.2

I'm still new to postgreSQL.  I have two tables I created that I want to go back and add Primary and Foreign key constraints for and no matter what I do I can't seem to add a foreign key.  Here's what I have:

Two Tables:

```
test=# \d statename
      Table "public.statename"
 Column |     Type      | Modifiers
--------+---------------+-----------
 code   | character(2)  | not null
 name   | character(30) |
Indexes:
    "statename_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (code)

test=# \d customer
          Table "public.customer"   
    Column   |     Type      | Modifiers
-------------+---------------+-----------
 customer_id | integer       |
 name        | character(30) |
 telephone   | character(20) |
 city        | character(25) |
 street      | character(40) |
 state       | character(2)  |
 zipcode     | character(10) |
 country     | character(20) |
```

Here's the command I'm running:

```
test=# ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT
state FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES
statename (code) >MATCH FULL;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  column "code" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

I'm looking at the column!  I know it exists!  Please help a brother out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code does not exist in your customer table. It's state.

```
ALTER TABLE customer 
ADD CONSTRAINT state FOREIGN KEY (state) 
REFERENCES statename (code) >MATCH FULL;
```

Comment: @Derek, which "state" determines foreign key and which column name? I try to add reference without giving it's name - such as by table creating.

Comment: So essentially the column name should not be specified but instead just the table name?